# 2 bugs since last CN1 updates (debug mode and Rounded Rectangle Border)

Tags: codenameone

As the title says, this post is meant to highlight two bugs that weren't there before last CN1 .jar updates:

1. Launching a codenameone app in debug mode fails
2. New or modified rounded rectangle border defined through the theme file are forced in top only mode

---

> 1. Launching a codenameone app in debug mode fails

I'll start with the 1st one as it is the most disturbing.

On Eclipse, launching the app in debug mode results in the following error (that I wasn't getting last week):

```
    ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection refused
    ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
    JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:735]
```

Initially, I thought that the socket was failing to initialize as the port was being used. That is also what you would mostly find on internet. So I checked the command line used to find out which port the socket was trying to connect to so that I can check if that port was available:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin\javaw.exe -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:54499 "-javaagent:C:\Users\Roman\eclipse\jee-2019-09\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\1095\0\.cp\lib\javaagent-shaded.jar" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\Work\Software_workspaces\Eclipse_IDE\Selisys\FirstOnPersonalPC\JavaSE.jar;D:\Work\Software_workspaces\Eclipse_IDE\Selisys\FirstOnPersonalPC\bin;D:\Work\Software_workspaces\Eclipse_IDE\Selisys\FirstOnPersonalPC\lib\CLDC11.jar;D:\Work\Software_workspaces\Eclipse_IDE\Selisys\FirstOnPersonalPC\lib\CodenameOne.jar;D:\Work\Software_workspaces\Eclipse_IDE\Selisys\FirstOnPersonalPC\lib\impl\cls;D:\Work\Software_workspaces\Eclipse_IDE\Selisys\FirstOnPersonalPC\lib\impl\stubs;D:\Work\Software_workspaces\Eclipse_IDE\Selisys\FirstOnPersonalPC\native\internal_tmp" com.codename1.impl.javase.Simulator be.selisys.rdf.firstonpersonalpc.FirstOnPersonalPC
```

We can see that it is attempting to use port 54499 (in fact, in gets incremented by 1 at each command line call). Now the funny thing is that this port (and the many following ones) is (are) effectively free!

I tried things such as rebooting Eclipse, my computer, check the dt_socket.dll, ... but none of that helped. After hours thought, I noticed the debug mode was working on other applications, but not on CodenameOne ones.

I then moved to another computer:

1. Turned off the internet, ran the debugger on a CN1 app ==> Works fine
2. Turned the internet  back on, send a built to get the jars updated, ran the debugger again ==> same error as above :(

Since I now know that it is obviously related to CN1 jars last update. Have you got any idea on how to solve that? How much time should we expect for a solution to come up? Any idea of a workaround? Maybe I can use the old jars, if there is a place to find them.

---

> 2. New or modified rounded rectangle border defined through the theme file are forced in top only mode

That is less important, but still annoying: basically, we can't use rounded rectangle borders using theme unless we have set them before the recent updates (I have no clue on since when the bug exists except that it is no older than 1 month). If you create/edit a rounded rectangle border, I will automatically be set to top only mode upon save. The current workaround I am using is creating a hard coded RoundRectBorder.

As above, the bug appears on any computer which get its jars updated.

---

Hope pointing these out will help them getting resolved earlier. :)

Cheers

Comment: I moved this post to GitHub codenameone /
CodenameOne Issues section as I realised it better belonged there. Apologies for that:

 - Issue [1](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2994)
 - Issue [2](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2995)

I see Steve Hannah already did a pull request for the second issue. Thanks, that was fast! Just waiting for the merge on master branch.